# Increase query efficiency in pyDrive

Tags: python, performance, query-performance, pydrive

I'm new to pyDrive (and Python in general). I'm working on a personal project and I ran into an efficiency problem.

> First, let me share you the code:

```
def initializeCSV(ID): # Id starts off as 'root' and then goes from there
    folderNames = []
    folderIDs = []

    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format(ID)}).GetList()
    for file in file_list:
        if file['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
            folderIDs.append(file['id'])
            folderNames.append(file['title'])

    with open('Folders.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for i in range(len(folderNames)):
            writer.writerow([folderNames[i], folderIDs[i]])

    for file in file_list:
        initializeCSV(file['id'])
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do here is query the entire account and create a .csv file with the names and IDs of `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` files. This file is going to be used later for other things I have in mind.

Now, the function works perfectly fine. But there's one problem, it takes like 3-4 minutes to query an account with around 50 folders inside. I was wondering if there was a faster or better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any profiling?

Comment: @AMC no, what's that? Sorry I'm really new to this.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) might help clarify things.